# How to update all packages from the same parent package in npm

Tags: npm, npm-install

Say my package.json includes these packages:

```
"@mantine/core": "^5.1.5",
"@mantine/dates": "^5.1.5",
"@mantine/form": "^5.1.5",
"axios": "^0.27.2",
"react": "^18.1.0"
```

How can I tell npm to update all `@mantine` packages at once? I can do `npm i @mantine/core@latest @mantine/dates@latest ...`, but am looking for a command like `npm i @mantine/*@latest`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

`npx npm-check-updates @mantine/* -u`

then install dependencies with your package manager, after running the command you should be prompted with

`npm install`

Related documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates